# Writing data on memory at different clocks

Tags: verilog, ram

I want to write data on a common memory coming from different clock domains how can I do that?
I have one common memory block and that memory block works on clock having frequency  clk. Now I want to write data on that memory coming from different clock domains i.e clk1, clk2, clk3, clk4 etc. How to do that?

I was thinking of using FIFO for each clock domain i.e. 1st FIFO have input clock clk1 and output at clk(same as memory), the 2md FIFO will have input clock clk2 and output at clk(same as memory) and so on.. But it seems that my design will outgrew if I will use large number of FIFOs. Kindly tell me the correct approach.

Comment: Can you give more information about your system and platform (that will increase chance of your question being answered)?

Comment: I have a memory working at system clock. Suppose my system clock is "clk" so my memory can read and write only at "clk". Now I have some channels which works at different clocks. Say my first channel gives data at "clk1", my second channels gives data at "clk2" and similarly other channels gives data at different clock frequencies. Now I want to store all the data coming from different channels (at different clock domain) to be written at my memory which works at system clock. So how to synchronize them? how to do this is my concern.

Answer (score 1):

To pass data-units (bytes, words etc) safely between clock domains the asynchronous FIFO is the only safe solution. Note that the FIFO does not have to be deep, but in that case you may need flow control.
You may need flow control anyway as you have many sources all accessing the same memory.

> But it seems that my design will outgrew if I will use large number of FIFOs.

Then you have a design problem: your FPGA is not large enough to implement the solution you have chosen. So either go to a bigger FPGA or find fundamentally different solution to your problem.

Comment: I have little knowledge about clock domain crossing. So the only solution I could think of is FIFO. So can you please suggest me any other solution if you know any. Thank you.

Comment: The only safe solution I know of **is** an asynchronous FIFO. You can use two registers with CDC (Clock Domain Crossing) handshaking but that is just an asynchronous FIFO with two entries.

Answer (score 0):

RAM can be write by clock domain A and read by clock domain B with different clocks (Dual-ported RAM):

http://www.asic-world.com/examples/verilog/ram_dp_ar_aw.html

This RAM should be used by some controller as asynchronous FIFO.

Many fpga have dedicated RAM components for example:
UFM Altera, Xilnx BRAM, Cypress Delta39K Cluster Memory Block etc.

Change your device if you have problem with large FIFO.